# What exactly does control state do in textbox and other controls

Tags: asp.net, control-state

I want to know about the similarity of the control state and ipostbackdatahandler.

I have disabled view state, then also value of text box in retained in it, why does this happen? Is it because of control state or "i post back data handler" interface.

if it is because of control state then please explain why.

Answer (score 0):

**How View State works?**

If View State is on for any control, during LoadViewstate, the View State data that got saved last time , gets populated in the control.  And in last, the SaveViewState method of every controls that are part of the control hiearchy, gets called and combined View State of all the controls gets base64  enocoded and saved.
So as we know the page is recreated every time page makes a trip to the server, the data persistence is adone with the help of viewstate.

even if we set off the View State of some controls like textbox, checkbox etc.. the data persists during postback. i.e., whenever a page is submitted or posted back to server, the entire form data is posted to the server as a collection with the request. The collection is in the form of NamedValue collection and this collection has the mapping with uniqueid of the control and the value of the control. You can read the data from the form collection by using the following code snippet

```
//Reading textbox value from the form collection
string textboxvalue = Request.Form[textbox1.UniqueID];
```

ASP.NET uses this primitive to update the control’s value. ASP.NET uses `IPostBackDataHandler`  for the controls that load the data from the form collection.
Actually all the controls which implement [IPostbackdatahandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackdatahandler.aspx), implement the method LoadPostData and RaisePostDataChangedEvent. But here the key method is LoadPostData, which returns true if the posted value is changed from earlier value and updates it with posted value, else it returns false.  Lets see the sample code here

```
public virtual bool LoadPostData(string uniqueId,
         NameValueCollection postedCollection) {
         //Getting the current value of control
         String currentValue = this.Text;
        //Getting the posted value from the form collection
         String postedValue = postedCollection[uniqueId];
        //Checks whether the posted value is changed from the current value, if yes updates it with the posted value and return yes
         if (currentValue == null || !currentValue.Equals(postedValue)) {
            this.Text = postedValue;
            return true;
         }
         //else return false
         return false;
      }
```

As from the Page Life Cycle, we can see LoadPostData is called after the LoadViewState, whether viewstate is on or not,  it gets populated from the posted data. That’s why the data get persisted even if viewstate is set to off for few controls. Following is the complete list of the controls, those implement IPostBackDataHandler.

- CheckBox
- CheckBoxList
- DropDownList
- HtmlInputCheckBox
- HtmlInputFile
- HtmlInputHidden
- HtmlInputImage
- HtmlInputRadioButton
- HtmlInputText
- HtmlSelect
- HtmlTextArea
- ImageButton
- ListBox
- RadioButtonList
- TextBox

[Source](http://brijbhushan.net/2011/02/07/why-textbox-persists-data-during-postback-even-if-view-state-set-to-off/)

`ViewState` is a messy hack to persist data between requests. The web is stateless and `ViewState` tries to make it appear stateful.

I believe the `TextBox` (and other `<input/>` controls) keep their value without `ViewState` because their values are POSTed in a form, while `Label` (`<span/>`) values are not.

Many Web Forms developers that care about page size will disable `ViewState` globally and only enable it for specific controls. If you use standard paging in a `GridView`, for example, you will need `ViewState` so that ASP.NET knows what page number the user clicked. You could use custom paging and use actual links for the page numbers and then turn on off `ViewState`.

Comment: But it still doesn't answer the core question that - "Retaining text box value after post back even if we Set EnableViewState to False ,is because of ControlState / IPostbackDataHandler?"